# How to use DeepQLearning in Julia for very large states?

Tags: machine-learning, julia

I would like to use the DeepQLearning.jl package from https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/DeepQLearning.jl. In order to do so, we have to do something similar to

```
using DeepQLearning
using POMDPs
using Flux
using POMDPModels
using POMDPSimulators
using POMDPPolicies

# load MDP model from POMDPModels or define your own!
mdp = SimpleGridWorld();

# Define the Q network (see Flux.jl documentation)
# the gridworld state is represented by a 2 dimensional vector.
model = Chain(Dense(2, 32), Dense(32, length(actions(mdp))))

exploration = EpsGreedyPolicy(mdp, LinearDecaySchedule(start=1.0, stop=0.01, steps=10000/2))

solver = DeepQLearningSolver(qnetwork = model, max_steps=10000, 
                             exploration_policy = exploration,
                             learning_rate=0.005,log_freq=500,
                             recurrence=false,double_q=true, dueling=true, prioritized_replay=true)
policy = solve(solver, mdp)

sim = RolloutSimulator(max_steps=30)
r_tot = simulate(sim, mdp, policy)
println("Total discounted reward for 1 simulation: $r_tot")
```

In the line `mdp = SimpleGridWorld()`, we create the MDP. When I was trying to create the MDP, I had the problem of very large state space. A state in my MDP is a vector in `{1,2,...,m}^n` for some `m` and `n`. So, when defining the function `POMDPs.states(mdp::myMDP)`, I realized that I must iterate over all the states which are very large, i.e., `m^n`.

Am I using the package in the wrong way? Or we must iterate the states even if there are exponentially many? If the latter, then what is the point of using Deep Q Learning? I thought, Deep Q Learning can help when the action and state spaces are very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeepQLearning does not require to enumerate the state space and can handle continuous space problems. 
DeepQLearning.jl only uses [the generative interface of POMDPs.jl](https://juliapomdp.github.io/POMDPs.jl/stable/generative/). As such, you do not need to implement the `states` function but just `gen` and `initialstate` (see the link on how to implement the generative interface).

However, due to the discrete action nature of DQN you also need `POMDPs.actions(mdp::YourMDP)` which should return an iterator over the action space.

By making those modifications to your implementation you should be able to use the solver.

The neural network in DQN takes as input a vector representation of the state. If your state is a `m` dimensional vector, the neural network input will be of size `m`. The output size of the network will be equal to the number of actions in your model.

In the case of the grid world example, the input size of the Flux model is 2 (x, y positions) and the output size is `length(actions(mdp))=4`.

Comment: So, if the action space is large, say an action is a vector in `{1,2,...,m}^n`, then how do I implement `POMDPs.actions()`. Should I use small values of `m` and `n`?

Comment: You can use `Iterators.product([1:m for i=1:n]...)`   to implement your action space. 
Since the output of the network is equal to the size of the action space (1 q value per action) you will certainly be limited to small `m` and `n`.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use DeepQLearning.jl when we have multi-agents? I mean I have two agents. Each agent is modelled as an MDP except that the reward for one MDP depends not only on the action of the corresponding agent but also on the action of the other agent of the other MDP. 

We could have two DQNs (one for each agent) and train the two agents on the two DQNs. The only problem is to calculate the reward for each agent using the actions of the two agents.

Comment: Currently it is not, we plan on releasing a multi agent package for POMDPs.jl at some point but not that soon. However, it should be feasible to reuse the much of the code from the current package and implement your own. I think stackoverflow is not appropriate for this discussion though. Feel free to open a post on https://discourse.julialang.org/ for a more in depth discussion.